# How to compare two addresses in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, code-injection, disassembly, opcode

I am trying to do some byte injection in a program to perform a specific task when `ecx+5C` is equal to a specific address which I supply an immediate value for. I'm trying to do something like the following: `cmp [ecx+5C], 1D59D3BC`. However I get an error. Does anyone know how I could compare a register+offset address to an immediate address in x86 assembly?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Take a look at [**Addressing in Assembler**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364162/addressing-in-assembler) and grab the .pdf referenced in the answer. (the short answer to your questions is *remove the `[ ]`s* to compare the address -- instead of the value stored at that address....)

Comment: Could be you're looking for  `cmp ecx, 1D59D3BCh - 5Ch`  ?

Comment: Do you want to compare the addresses, or compare the memory contents pointed to by those addresses?  Addresses are just like  integers that you can compare with `cmp`, as Paul H says.  (It usually makes most sense to check flags afterwards for above/below, rather than signed greater/less.  nvm, you're just looking for equal)

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to do something like the following: `cmp [ecx+5C], 1D59D3BC`.
>   However I get an error.

Possible causes why this will fail:

- You need to specify an hex prefix or suffix for the assembler to accept your instruction.
- You need to specify the size of the operation. The assembler doesn't guess for you.

Try any of the following (depends on your assembler):

```
cmp dword ptr [ecx + 5Ch], 1D59D3BCh
cmp dword ptr [ecx + 0x5C], 0x1D59D3BC
cmp dword [ecx + 5Ch], 1D59D3BCh
cmp dword [ecx + 0x5C], 0x1D59D3BC
```

---

> Does anyone know how I could compare a register+offset address to an immediate address in x86 assembly?

```
lea eax, [ecx + 5Ch]   ;put the address in EAX
cmp eax, 1D59D3BCh   ;compare with the immediate
```

But shorter as PaulH showed in a comment:

```
cmp ecx, 1D59D3BCh - 0000005Ch
```